# Why does ArcGIS cause problems with numeric columns?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql

When I load my database into ArcMap or ArcCatalog, columns with datatype `numeric(1,0)`, `numeric(2,0)` ... until `numeric(9,0)` get 0 values in each row, but if I convert the datatype to `numeric(10,0)` , or higher, with
`ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_col TYPE numeric(10,0) USING my_col::numeric(10,0)`
the correct values are displayed. The numbers are just single-digit numbers in the `numbers(1,0)` datatype columns and up to two-digit numbers in the `numbers(2,0)` datatype columns. So why does ArcGIS convert all these numbers to 0 when the datatype is `number(1-9,0)`?

Comment: Not a Esri DBMS expert, but [this page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm#GUID-70728949-2016-4DB5-A723-5493B4330AE0) on field types lead me to ask why not use a short int on the DBMS side rather than the numeric type?

Comment: Yeah, I was also wondering about that one, but this does not legitimize the awkward behavior of ArcGIS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esri registered this problem as a bug and will fix it at sometime in the future. The best workaround for me is to convert every column to double precision data type.